# The event listener can't access my handleChange function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**App.js (parent component)**

```
import React from "react";
import TodoItem from "./TodoItem";
import todosData from "./todosData";
import "./styles.css";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      todos: todosData
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(id) {
    console.log(`${id} Clicked!`);
  }

  render() {
    const todoItems = this.state.todos.map(function (item) {
      return (
        <TodoItem
          key={item.id}
          text={item.text}
          completed={item.completed}
          item={item}
          handleChange={this.handleChange}
        />
      );
    });
    return <div className="todo-list">{todoItems}</div>;
  }
}

export default App;
```

**TodoItem.js (child component)**

```
import React from "react";

function TodoItem(props) {
  return (
    <div className="todo-item">
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        checked={props.completed}
        onChange={() => props.handleChange(props.item.id)}//PROBLEM LINE
      />
      <p>{props.text}</p>
    </div>
  );
}

export default TodoItem;
```

Returns the following:

CONSOLE: Could not consume error: Error {}

PROBLEMS: props.handleChange is not a function

I used binding and I tested to see that my handleChange() was properly defined. Other props are being read but props.handleChange isn't.

Comment: handleChange() is defined directly below my constructor in App.js. App is a class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
const todoItems = this.state.todos.map(function (item) {
  return (
    <TodoItem
      key={item.id}
      text={item.text}
      completed={item.completed}
      item={item}
      handleChange={this.handleChange}
    />
  );
});
```

When you say this.handleChange in here you are trying to get handleChange from the function which receives 'item' in the map. handleChange is not defined in that function.

So you need to change the function which receives item to an arrow function which take as this the this of the outer function. Like this:

```
const todoItems = this.state.todos.map(item => 
        <TodoItem
          key={item.id}
          text={item.text}
          completed={item.completed}
          item={item}
          handleChange={this.handleChange}
        />
      );
```

Answer (score 2):

```
class TestTodo extends React.Component {

    state = {
      todos: todosData
    };
  

  handleChange = (id) => {
    console.log(`${id} Clicked!`);
  }

  render() {

    const todoItems = this.state.todos.map( item=> {
      return (
        <TodoItem
          key={item.id}
          text={item.text}
          completed={item.completed}
          item={item}
          handleChange={this.handleChange}
        />
      );
    });
    return <div className="todo-list">{todoItems}</div>;
  }
}

export default TestTodo;


import React from "react";

const  TodoItem = props => {
    const handleChange = () =>{
        props.handleChange(props.item.id)
    }

  return (
    <div className="todo-item">
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        checked={props.completed}
        onChange={handleChange}
      />
      <p>{props.text}</p>
    </div>
  );
}

export default TodoItem;
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! Does React only work with ES6 syntax?

Comment: i think it's a scope problem because This is not defined inside the callback function u wrote inside map() so u have to use ES6 syntax

Comment: u can also use this syntax instead   const todoItems = this.state.todos.map(function (item) {
      return (
        <TodoItem
          key={item.id}
          text={item.text}
          completed={item.completed}
          item={item}
          handleChange={this.handleChange}
        />
      );
    }.bind(this));
    return <div className="todo-list">{todoItems}</div>;
  }

Answer (score 0):

you need to bind the map function or use the arrow function. because in this case the `this` in `'this.handleChange'` refers to the map's callback function and not to the class that is why it gives you `undefined`. so you have two solutions for that problem.

**soln#1 : arrow function**

```
render() {
        const todoItems = this.state.todos.map( (item) => {
          return (
            <TodoItem
              key={item.id}
              text={item.text}
              completed={item.completed}
              item={item}
              handleChange={this.handleChange}
            />
          );
        });
        return <div className="todo-list">{todoItems}</div>;
     }
```

**soln#2: bind map's callback function**

```
render() {
        const todoItems = this.state.todos.map( function(item) {
          return (
            <TodoItem
              key={item.id}
              text={item.text}
              completed={item.completed}
              item={item}
              handleChange={this.handleChange}
            />
          );
        }.bind(this));
        return <div className="todo-list">{todoItems}</div>;
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

just change your return function to use an arrow function like:

```js
render() {
    const todoItems = this.state.todos.map((item) => {
      return (
        <TodoItem
          key={item.id}
          text={item.text}
          completed={item.completed}
          item={item}
          handleChange={this.handleChange.bind(this, item.id)}
        />
      );
    });
    return <div className="todo-list">{todoItems}</div>;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

and change your TodoItem component to something like this:

```js
import React from "react";

function TodoItem(props) {
  return (
    <div className="todo-item">
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        checked={props.completed}
        onChange={props.handleChange} //PROBLEM LINE
      />
      <p>{props.text}</p>
    </div>
  );
}

export default TodoItem;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

demo [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-lehmann-9m1xh?file=/src/App.js)